# Floating Scrolling fragments in android through Java?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, horizontal-scrolling, cardview

I would like to implement the following behavior in an android application:

[image]

So should I use fragments with horizontal ScrollView, a ViewPager or what exactly? Would it be better to use CardView?

And how to add the 2 dots at the bottom to show that we still have for example another page to show?

Finally, I need only one fragment/CardView to be present at a time. That is, I don't want to see half of the first fragment and half the second. That would be annoying.

I would like to know in general what pieces to use for this purpose.

Any help is much appreciated!!

Comment: Viewpager. For the dots you can use JakeWharton's ViewPagerIndicator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use ViewPager.  It will give you all of the functionality you're looking for and will allow you to add or remove pages easily in the future.

You will have to manually create a page indicator (the dots at the bottom) or use a library like this:

https://github.com/romandanylyk/PageIndicatorView